# Mailer Error: The following From address failed: info@domainname : Error: too much mail from serverip, 450, 4.7.1 using PHPmailer

Tags: php, apache, email, phpmailer

I'm sending emails with a php function sendEmail(), which gets triggered through an API call. The function is called up to 3-5 times in a minute but max 300 times a day.

Sometimes I get this error and the emails don’t get sent.

> Mailer Error: The following From address failed: info@domain :
> MAIL FROM command failed,Error: too much mail from Server IP,
> 450,4.7.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Error:
> too much mail from Server IP

I always send a second email to my email account. And here I also get sometimes the same error.
My Email server allows me to send 1000 emails in 10 minutes and max 3 SMTP connections at the same time.

My Function:

```
function sendEmail($serverName, $from, $subject, $to, $filePath, $msg){

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {

//Server settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding   = 'base64';
$mail->Host       = $serverName;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = $from;
$mail->Password   = <PASSWORD>;
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;

$mail->Port       = 465;

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($from, $subject);
$mail->addAddress($to);     //Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($from, 'Info Domain');
$mail->addCC($to);
$mail->addBCC($to);

//Attachments
$mail->addAttachment($filePath);       

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $msg;

$mail->send();
return true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  return false;
}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: You're being blocked by your ISP's spam blocker. If you're doing this from a residential ISP, you need to get a business account.

Comment: I already have a business account. I'm not sure if I did understand you right but like I said I'm available to send up to 1000 emails every 10 minutes

Comment: I think the issue is about the connection?!

Comment: Either the function is being called more than you think, or your limits are lower than you think. The function only sends one email, so there's nothing there you can change to solve this.

Comment: How would you prove that? Actually, I can see how many peoples I have sent emails per day and I also get an email every time I send an email.

Comment: The best way to throttle this is to install a local mail server (e.g. postfix) and relay through that, and configure it with those sending limits. You will be able to submit messages to it as fast as you like and the mail server will deal with upstream limits. You don't want to write an MTA in PHP...

Comment: And some of the emails, I'm not sure if all but they get sent after a while. Sometimes 1 day later

Comment: @AlvLocoKopf I'm just assuming that the message from the SMTP server isn't lying when it says "too much mail". What else could that mean other than you've exceeded a rate limit?

Comment: So I should install into the Server my own mail handler? e.g. Postfix

Answer (score 1):

In your code I could see the following:

```
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->addCC($to);
$mail->addBCC($to);
```

Why you have added '`$mail->addCC`' and '`$mail->addBCC`' to the same recipient '$to'?
Your mail server can count CC and BCC as different mail addresses and each send process will be counted as 3 mails, not one. Just remove `$mail->addCC($to)` and `$mail->addBCC($to)`. They are not need if you already have '`$mail->addAddress($to);`'.

Comment: Oh, ok I will try it.

Comment: do you have tried?